# Java: how to check if BufferedReder is Empty?(code included)

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader

Im practicing some stuff for my java networking exam and I cant seem to figure this out.
I wrote a simple server program that is suppose to ask my client program a question and then wait fro a reply from the client before moving ahead and processing the answer.

heres a bit of my code:

```
//Server:
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())
                    );
String answer1;
while(!in.ready()){    //wait till client replies
}
 answer1 = in.readLine();
//do something with answer1
//repeat for answer 2 and so on.....
```

the above loop does not work and the server just runs the entire program without waiting for a reply form the client. the in.readLine() statement by itself(without the while loop) does not wait either.

Is there any simple way to check if the BufferedReader is empty or atleast get the program to wait for a reply? I know that i can't test for it being null either because as long as the sockets are connected, that wont be true.

Comment: What do you mean by `the server just runs the entire program without waiting for a reply`? You have a call to `BufferedReader.readLine` in your program, are you saying the data returned is empty? Or that the call blocks forever and does nothing?

Comment: yup, if i put in bufferedreader.readline() by itself, i get empty data, even before the client gets a chance to reply and moves on to the next question. Im assuming that this is normal since the buffered reader will always have some data in it and will only be null if there is no connection between the sockets.

Comment: the reply on the client side is supposed to be done manually by me via command prompt by the way, but i dont get a chance to do so as the server does not wait.

Comment: No wait, I havent used the bufferedreader earlier on. this is the first input read for the program so it should be empty

Comment: How do i flush a buffered reader by the way, i could only find something called reset() in the api documentation which just resets the entire buffer and kills the connection.

Comment: If you are implementing a reply/response protocol then you will need to define some way of indicating that a message is 'done'. Alternatively you can read up until you get a non-empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need this. Just call readLine(). It will block until data arrives.

> if i put in bufferedreader.readline() by itself, i get empty data

No you don't. You don't get anything. The method blocks until data arrives.

You have a fundamental misunderstanding somewhere.

Comment: Your'r right, i tested this line separately and it worked. I guess there must be something else wrong in my code.
Thanks :D